# Populate a dropdown by another select

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created this:

```
User: <select id="sel_depart">
    <option value="0">All users</option>    
<?php
$all_users = User::getUsersAdmin();
foreach($all_users as $value){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" <?php if($user_id == $value->id) echo "selected" ?>><?php echo $value->username; ?></option>
<?php } ?> 
</select>

Locker: <select id="sel_user">
    <option value="0">All lockers</option>  
</select>
```

And I have this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sel_depart").change(function(){
        var user_id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/get_lockers.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {user_id:user_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;

                $("#sel_user").empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i]['id'];
                    var name = response[i]['name'];

                    $("#sel_user").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

get_lockers.php output is:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"edees"},{"id":3,"name":"20171114_154920"}]
```

What is wrong? When I select an user from dropdown, locker dropdown is not populated with options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try this, it should work!

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#sel_depart").change(function(){
    var user_id = 2;
        $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/get_lockers.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {user_id:user_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response){
        //Add this line and try
  response =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
          var len = response.length;
            $('#sel_user').find('option').remove().end();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var id = response[i]['id'];
                var name = response[i]['name'];
                var option = new Option(name, id);
               $('#sel_user').find('option').end().append($(option));

   }
   }
    });
});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<p>Select Department</p>
<select id="sel_depart" name="this" class="input-sm input-s form-control">
    <option>Test A</option>
    <option>Test B</option>
    <option>Test C</option>
    <option>Test D</option>
</select>

<p>Select User</p>

<select id="sel_user" name="this" class="input-sm input-s form-control">
    <option>Test A</option>
    <option>Test B</option>
    <option>Test C</option>
    <option>Test D</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have any error in console but on tab Response after made POST to get_lockers.php I have only  [ ]   and when I go to `get_lockers.php?user_id=2`  it show me  `[{"id":2,"name":"edees"},{"id":3,"name":"20171114_154920"}]`

Comment: Did you inspect the #sel_user element?

Comment: `<select id="sel_user" name="this" class="input-sm input-s form-control"></select>` that is

Comment: Is not working mate, when I choose option from first dropdown ajax don't make POST

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your ajax request. You can run this snip and see it working.

Comment: What's the response you are seeing in alert?

Comment: Try with the hardcoded response first and see if it works, if yes then check your response.

Comment: it is an empty alert, but when I access get_lockers.php?user_id=2 I get `[{"id":2,"name":"edees"},{"id":3,"name":"20171114_154920"}]`

Comment: Is the file get_lockers.php live? Can you share the URL?

Comment: i am getting Failed to load https://panel.cpabeko.com/admin/get_lockers.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: hmmm, need to be accessible, it is working at me and to other devices.

Comment: Wait I will create a php file and echo the response and test it

Comment: I getting `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data[Learn More]`

Comment: So there is something wrong with your JSON response its not well formated, can you share your php file?

Comment: I think is good formated because output is `[{"id":2,"name":"edees"},{"id":3,"name":"20171114_154920"}]`

Comment: response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); try that just to be sure as I tested it, and it's working locally 

Comment: it is working mate, good job! Update your response to make a vote! Thank you!